# Inequalities in a triangle.

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle, with $BC$ as it's largest side. $D,E$ and $F$ are points on $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ respectively (inside the boundaries of the triangle).

Prove that :-
i)$BC \geq DE$
ii)$BC \geq EF$

And hence prove that no straight line can be drawn in a triangle such that it is greater than the greatest side.

I tried this by joining B and E and then using angle inequalities for the first part, but there was a lot of ambiguity in my answer.

Comment: Can someone please format the inequality signs?

Comment: Formatting done. Besides, what have you tried by yourself ?

Comment: Because you have modified your text meanwhile, I suppose.

Comment: You were right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

i) $\angle BDE+ \angle EDC=180^{\circ}$.

Without loss of generality $BDE \ge 90^{\circ}$. Then $DC\ge DE$ (opposite the larger angle is larger side) $ \Rightarrow BC \ge DE$

ii) similarly